# JUnitLaunchShortcut with several Class Tests

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, junit

When I execute this piece of code:

```
Object[] segments = new Object[2];
segments[0] = // JUnit Test Class 1
segments[1] = // JUnit Test Class 2

TreePath treepath = new TreePath(segments);
TreeSelection treeselection = new TreeSelection(treepath);

JUnitLaunchShortcut j = new JUnitLaunchShortcut();
j.launch(treeselection, ILaunchManager.RUN_MODE);
```

Eclipse/JUnit Plugin only execute **JUnit Test Class 2**, perhaps execute the two Test Class but only show at JUnit View the last Test Class (maybe)....

What you think? How can I 'launch' the all Test Class?

Comment: I check the JUnitLaunchShortcut code and verified that code cast TreeSelection for IStructuredSelection and call _launch(Object[] elements, String mode)_ ... On this entire process ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy only can setAttribute for one test, but I need for N tests... :( How can I create ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy to run several Tests?! Or, how can I add multiple ILaunchConfigurationWorkingCopy for VMArg?

Comment: After a lot of hours, I think it is impossible to do what I want... RunConfiguration of Eclipse doesn't support run for several Test Cases selected by me! Only runs a **SingleTestClass** or one **Project**, **Package** or **SourceFolder**, doesn't run multiple Test Cases from several packages. (I'm sad :( )

Answer (score 1):

As you say in your comment, the JUnit plugin for eclipse doesn't support multiple selections in a configuration. However, the `org.eclipse.jdt.junit.launcher.JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate` does support multiple test launching. When you select a project/package/test class in the JUnit plugin, and select Run as JUnit test, it passes the configuration to JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate, where it evaluates the tests to be run. If there is one, it calls RemoteTestRunner like this:

```
RemoteTestRunner -test TestClass
```

If it finds more than one file, it runs like this:

```
RemoteTestRunner -testfile testNamesxxxx.txt
```

where testNamesxxx.test is a file which contains a list of tests to run, for instance:

```
uk.co.farwell.junit.parameters.ParameterTest
uk.co.farwell.junit.run.AllTests
uk.co.farwell.junit.run.Class1Test
```

This file is created in your temp directory. So, one possible way to explore is to extend JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate and override the evaluateTests method, which has a signature like:

```
protected IMember[] evaluateTests(ILaunchConfiguration configuration, IProgressMonitor monitor) throws CoreException {
```

And you're left with how to communicate the list of tests via the ILaunchConfiguration, but you can extend this for your plugin as well.

Comment: It's sounds easy, but it's very difficulty... It's difficulty to understand how to extend ILaunchConfiguration, I cannot understand how can I add more test and after that call RemoteTestRunner... :(

Comment: Hi Matthew, I extend the JUnitLaunchConfigurationDelegate and override the evaluateTests method like you said... After I create a [ILaunchConfiguration](http://pastie.org/2890492), but if I fill the ATTR_TEST_CONTAINER attribute with the HandleIdentifier of Project, Package or Class the launcher execute the tests presented on that Project, Package or Class and not the tests returned by my override evaluateTests... If I don't fill that attribute, the Eclipse returns "The input type of the launch configuration does not exist"...

Comment: Ok, I check again my code and I have wrong line ILaunch launch = wc.launch(ILaunchManager.RUN_MODE, null); I change this to ILaunch launch = new Launch(wc, ILaunchManager.RUN_MODE, null); after that I check the testNamesxxxx.txt and it has the name of tests that I want... :) 
Now the problem is JUnit isn't run :( , nothing happen, and I think the problem is in the creation of Launch...